# sshfs: experiencing data loss

Tags: mount, osx, emacs, sshfs, fuse

I am connecting to a filesystem on a remote server via sshfs. What I do is just to modify these files with emacs. From time to time I am experiencing data loss.

While I work on a file and try to save the changes I get that the file has changed on the disk and Emacs asks me if I want to save the changes or not. So I choose no, if I choose yes the  modification are not saved on the remote cluster but only on the local mount point.

Now I was working on a file, Emacs told me that the file had been modified on the disk, so I choose to not save the changes and then Emacs asks me if I want to keep the recent modification I said no, and the file is completely gone. I don't know what it is wrong with this, because I have used sshfs many other times and it has always been fine.

I am using Mac 10.6.8, sshfs 2.4 and fuse4x library version: FUSE 2.8.7 / fuse4x 0.9.2